# How to turn off javadoc on eclipse code completion

Tags: eclipse, ide

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpQEp.jpg)

I'm trying to disable the yellow tooltip box which is about javadoc, but cannot find the answer about this option.

Almost all of them say about 'hover javadoc tooltip' which can be disabled in preference > JAVA > Editors > Hover.

So can I turn off this option or can't?

Comment: _Java > Editors > Hovers_ are something other than the additional information box for the currently selected content assist proposal. There are proposals with and without corresponding Javadoc. As far as I know, it can't be turned off. Without the Javadoc, you would have to choose a proposal blindly. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @howlger Because It induces a little delay to show Javadoc, and I'm accustomed to using IntelliJ editor not showing that textbox. Anyway I have to adapt to eclipse then.

Comment: The displaying happens asynchronously and does not block the input. If it does, you are using a very old Eclipse version.

Comment: the loading process for javadoc is blocking the textinput. using latest eclipse version. i would like to turn it off aswell.